# Re-stud old winter tires

Tags: tires, maintenance, vw

Can old studded winter tires have old worn rusted studs removed and Re-studded with a new batch???

any tips either way

[image: pick of old studded tires]

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The original tungsten carbide studs were outlawed in any state they might be used in the 70's. As I remember Canada could not decide if the road damage was worth possible safety improvement. Minnesota found interstate clover leafs destroyed in one season by studs; that is 6 " deep ruts in concrete and asphalt pavements. Amoco Oil research did contract testing for MN , Utah and maybe other states.( I did not work on it but friends did .) The red rust from your old studs shows they were steel  so this may be academic as the steel will wear away quickly.

Comment: intersting.. never knew studs were Tungsten Carbide at one pint in the past.. always thought they were Steel... wonder if I can find TC ones in canada.

Answer (score 4):

They can, indeed, but it's not worth it.  I did this for Colorado in-laws many years ago.

Getting the old ones out was problematic.  Not only do the heads snap off, even if they come out clean, the "holes" heal and unless you keep a sharp eye, are difficult to locate to install the fresh stud.

However, *on the cheap* I discovered it's perfectly reasonable to just leave the existing, and install more new studs close, but not too close, to the originals.  These are not so location-dependent that another batch won't work just fine unless they are installed in the same position.

Again, I say "on the cheap"...  Be prepared to check air pressure frequently, which is always an issue anyway.  Frankly, the kind of tires that accept studs are not so expensive anyway, so depending on your budget, you might just want a clean slate.

A further aside is that nothing beats studs except chains (yes, I'm that old), but honestly ... modern snow/ice tires are incredibly effective.  No, I'd still want studs in a Colorado mountain pass (I-25, or maybe Grand Junction to Mesa) but I can drive on the new "snow" tires year round if I want.  Once the "snow" portion wears away (quickly in the dry), you are just left with the normal sipes and a normal wearing tire.  And it always amazes me how inexpensive these new snow/ice tires are compared to the same size performance radials.  Check out one of the online retailers for Bridgestone Blizzack or the Swedish Nokian Hakkapelittahakena  (no, that isn't spelled even marginally right) as well as a half dozen other competant brands.

Cheap rims are nice to keep them mounted year-round.  The money might be well-spent considering the new curse words you will invent attempting to restud old dry tires.

Comment: I would note to you, these tires are winter tires built for studs. The holes for the studs are pre-molded in the tire to begin with, so there's no worry about the rubber healing. Studs usually sit fairly deep within the rubber as well, so them "staying put" in the rubber should not be an issue. Digging out old studs can be problematic. This damages the holes and makes it far harder for the holes to contain the new studs. You could definitely replace studs in empty holes, though. I don't really like studs, either, so know exactly where you're coming from. Chains are worse, but sometimes needed.

Comment: partially correct in that these tires were designed for studs... but they were bought between 2001 and 2003 from Walmart and the shop guy installed the studs from a box he showed me. was kinda assuming I could use a heat gun make the removal much easier.... but may that is wishful thinking.

Comment: @HestonT.Holtmann  I doubt you will be able to get enough heat deep enough to help.  Try taking out 10 on one tire, and count how many were easy and how many were a nightmare.  Keep track of how long it takes you.  The simple math will allow you to compare to your personal time and angst thresholds.  I myself am so insanely cheap, I become a masochist and put $300 worth of effort into saving $40.  You may be a much wiser individual.  However,this is one of the few tasks I eventually decided I wanted nothing to do with ever again.

Comment: thanks all... I will just run them as is for one more season (central Canada) and look for a New (or uses) pair in spring 2017 when things go on sale

Answer (score 1):

I re-stud my winter tires all the time.  This will be the third season for these in Saskatchewan.  Removing them is simple with a side cutter pliers. Just push the point of the pliers up against each side of the stud and grab it and pry it out. Took about 5 minutes per tire and then just re-stud.  Maybe wear a glove though if the pliers has a rubber handle because it will give you a nasty blister on the inside of your thumb.  I noticed that I had lost two studs over the coarse of two seasons but I have no idea what the failure rate might be on newly studded tires.  Simple cheap process!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmed tip... ends up the tires in the pic we so old 10+ years, that they blew out and shredded themselves last winter (was nasty; and intresting), currently have non-studded used winters on.. but wil keep in mind for next time

Comment: ... and being form MB.. i rest assured SK dudes know there stuff when it comes to studded tires.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I run studded snow tires in the winter here in New Hampshire from November through March and find that they are good for about 3 seasons. After three seasons I leave them on the car for the remainder of their tread life and buy new studded tires the following year.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how this actually answers the question? They are asking about replacing old studs, not the tires themselves of the longevity as you've stated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Glad to see you are jumping in to answer questions. Although your experience is valuable, it does not really answer the question being asked about old tires being "Re-studded". I would suggest answering that and adding your experience to it.